# django-tables2 permissions in TemplateColumn

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-tables2

I feel like I have read about this a hundred times but I still can't figure out how to use permissions within a **django-tables2** `TemplateColumn`.

My goal is to be able to render buttons in a column based on permissions that a user may have or may not have on a given model. That does not sound complicated to me and from what I have read I should be able to use something like `{% if perms.myapp.delete_mymodel %}` to achieve what I'd like to do.

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work as I expect:

```
import django_tables2 as tables


MY_MODEL_ACTIONS = """
{% if perms.myapp.change_mymodel %}
<a href="{% url 'myapp:my_model_edit' pk=record.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
{% endif %}
{% if perms.myapp.delete_mymodel %}
<a href="{% url 'myapp:my_model_delete' pk=record.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
{% endif %}
"""


class MyModelTable(tables.Table):
    # some columns
    actions = tables.TemplateColumn(
        verbose_name="",
        template_code=MY_MODEL_ACTIONS,
    )

    class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            # some columns
            "actions",
        )
```

When rendering the table no issues are triggered but the column just do not display any buttons (yes I do have the permissions for them to show up). Removing the `{% if … %}` clauses, thus removing the permission checks, allows the buttons to be seen of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bit tricky. I defined my own template to render the table and did not used the `{% render_table table %}` tag inside it. Due to this the context was not reachable from the `TemplateColumn` code.

To fix this, I changed my template a bit and move my table rendering custom code to another template file. After that I used the `render_table` tag like this `{% render_table table 'includes/table.html' %}`

After this, the code that I mentioned above in the column works just fine, permissions are honored like expected.

Answer (score 0):

What adds `perms` to your context?`TemplateColumns` do not have the same context as the template `{{ render_table table }}` is called from, so you must be a little more explicit.

[The documentation for `render_table` mentions it will attach the context of the calling template to `table.context`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/template-tags.html#render-table), so this should fix your problem:

```
MY_MODEL_ACTIONS = """
{% if table.context.perms.myapp.change_mymodel %}
    <a href="{% url 'myapp:my_model_edit' pk=record.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
{% endif %}
{% if table.context.perms.myapp.delete_mymodel %}
    <a href="{% url 'myapp:my_model_delete' pk=record.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
{% endif %}
"""
```